# Flutter pub get error ( open_file_safe ^3.2.3 and file_picker ^5.2.2 ) how to fix this?

Tags: flutter, filepicker

**After running pub get i am getting the following error** (First time build)

```
Because file_picker >=5.0.0 depends on ffi ^2.0.1 and open_file_safe 3.2.3 depends on ffi ^1.0.0, file_picker >=5.0.0 is incompatible with open_file_safe 3.2.3.
And because no versions of open_file_safe match >3.2.3 <4.0.0, file_picker >=5.0.0 is incompatible with open_file_safe ^3.2.3.
So, because app depends on both open_file_safe ^3.2.3 and file_picker ^5.2.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because app depends on both open_file_safe ^3.2.3 and file_picker ^5.2.2, version solving failed.)
```

I tried to run `pub get` command and expected it to run successfully without any error.

Comment: Try: In pubspec.yaml file instead of specifying package version use any, like file_picker: ^5.0.0 user file_picker: any. This will fetch compatible package version.

Comment: OR find file_picker version that depends on ffi 1.0.0

Comment: This fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/75355100/5734049

Answer (score 3):

As a fast solution for now you can use

https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex

if and only if your app is only running on mobile OS