# How use open_file and file_picker packages together in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use both file_picker package and the open_file package but their latest versions is not compatible with eachother as you can se in the error message below.open_file has not been updated for the last 18 months so maybe it starts to get depricated?

Maybe there is another way to open a file instead of the open_file package?
Because if I want to use them both I have to switch to a very old version of file_picker.

**The error message:**

```
Because open_file >=3.1.0 depends on ffi ^1.0.0 and file_picker 5.2.4 depends on ffi ^2.0.1, open_file >=3.1.0 is incompatible with file_picker 5.2.4.
        And because no versions of file_picker match >5.2.4 <6.0.0, open_file >=3.1.0 is incompatible with file_picker ^5.2.4.
        So, because my_app depends on both file_picker ^5.2.4 and open_file ^3.2.1, version solving failed.
        pub get failed (1; So, because my_app depends on both file_picker ^5.2.4 and open_file ^3.2.1, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: Try using older version of file_picker which depends on ffi^1.0.0

Comment: I would recommend against using old versions of a package, our using packages that are not up to date with their dependencies. Soon you'll run into more dependency conflicts with other packages.
Only change is to clone the open_file package and try to update its dependencies. However, you'll need to support it yourself, going forward.

Comment: Or maybe ping the maintainers, asking for an update. Last commit seems to be dated August, 2022.

Comment: Ok, Thats what i thought. I know that I could use an older version but that doesn’t seem sustainable in the long run. 
It says that the latest version 3.2.1 was published  19 months ago. Strange when it seems to be a significant package for flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the package's ffi dependency  Add `dependency_overrides` to  `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  ffi: ^2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [open_file_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_plus) instead of open_file,I will recommend
open_file_plus: ^3.4.1 with
file_picker: ^5.1.1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34840591)